# Alternative approach to solve $a(x dy +2y dx)=xy dy$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the solution of $a(x dy +2y dx)=xy dy$

My attempt:
$Mdx + Ndy = 0$ where $M=2ay, N=ax-xy,M_y=2a , N_x = a-y, \frac{N_x - M_y}{M} = \frac{-y-a}{2ay} \implies $Integrating factor $=\frac{e^{(\frac{-y}{2a})}}{\sqrt y}$

THis gives

Solution --> $2ax \sqrt y = ce^{(\frac{y}{2a})}$, c being integrating constant

I want to know is there any other simpler alternative approach to solve this???? kindly provide me alternative simpler approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just divide whole expression by $xy$ and integrate

$$a(\frac{dy}{y} + 2\frac{dx}{x})= dy$$

:)

Comment: this is too gud :)

Comment: Thanks but  its same as variable separation :)

Answer (score 2):

this equation is separable, $$\frac{y'(x)}{\frac{y(x)}{a-y(x)}}=-\frac{2a}{x}$$

Answer (score 1):

Dividing by $xy,$

$$ \frac{dy}{y} + \frac{2dx}{x}= d(y/a) $$

straightforward integration

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is an easier way to solve $$a(x dy +2y dx)=xy dy$$ Rearrange terms to get the separable equation $$x(a-y)dy=-2ydx$$Upon solving this equation we get $$aln(y)-y=-2ln(x)+C$$